# Is there a way from the iOS SDK to query a user's entire in-app purchase history?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

For metrics purposes, I need to view historical in-app purchase data for my app's users.  I am aware of the [restoreCompletedTransactions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506123-restorecompletedtransactions) API but it appears this is limited to transactions ["that can be restored"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506123-restorecompletedtransactions).  Is there a way to get a history of *all* transactions, even non-restorable?

Answer (score 0):

First Part of your question: the historical transactional data is stored in the receipt.

To answer the second part of your question, previous consumable purchases and non-renewable subscriptions that have already been used or expired will not be in the receipt so they will need to be kept track of ahead of time.